# indexeddb Invalid state error by call-stack?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Again, i got some question on indexeddb. I´m getting a

> InvalidStateError: A Mutation operation was attempted on a database
>   that did not allow mutations.

and also an

```
AbortError
```

Here is my code:

```
DB_LINK.prototype.pushStoreNumeric = function () 
{ 
    // Saving Values 
    var _temp = 0; 
    var _version = this.link.version; 
    var _name = this.link.name; 
    var that = this; 
    var _objectStoreNames = this.link.objectStoreNames; 

    // Close DB 
    this.link.close(); 
    this.state = 4; 

    // Reopen Database    
    this.req = indexedDB.open(_name,_version+1); // Abort error here
    this.req.onupgradeneeded = function () { 
    that.state = 1; 


    // Get Number of object stores 
    _temp = _objectStoreNames.length; 

    if(_temp != 0) 
    { 
        // Already object stores: read highest value 
        _temp = parseInt(_objectStoreNames[_objectStoreNames.length - 1]); 
    } 
    that.link.createObjectStore(_temp); // InvalidStateError here
};
```

I have marked per comment where the errors occur.

The InvalidStateError occures first, the AbortError follows.

I am calling this function inside another onsuccess function of the same database. Might this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `this.link`? That's probably the problem. You need to be doing `createObjectStore` on the database instance created by the `indexedDB.open` request. So either `this.req.result.createObjectStore` or (if you change to `this.req.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {`) you could use `e.target.result.createObjectStore`.

More generally, I can't really comment on what your code is supposed to be doing because I can only see a snippet, but it looks really weird how you are incrementing the version every time this is called. Probably you don't actually want to be doing that. You might want to read a bit more documentation.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed out the problem.  `this.link` _was_ my link to the database, before i closed it. I didn´t store the new link in `this.link`, what is equal to `that.link` (because of `var that = this` in the shown code).  What i generally want is to do with this function is adding a new store to a Database. The stores in the database have numeric names (by my definition) and now this code works! And as i can only create new stores in an versionchange transaction, i have to increase the version of the database - so thats correct. Thank You!